# Safari Mobile app banner changes the viewport height

Tags: javascript, ios, css, dom, mobile-safari

[image]

The banner below the **address bar** is changing the height and not even a part of DOM.

`Position: fixed` elements on the bottom are hidden.

You can view this by

1. Open https://www.ounass.ae/clothing/ in `Safari - iOS smart phones`
2. Scroll down to view this App Banner
3. Click on `Filter By` button.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I know that this is related with the Universal Links but haven't found a way to disable the bar or to dismiss it.

Comment: @TitoNobre unfortunately nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue but this may not be the fix but a work-around.

```
const updatePositionOfCtaButton = () => {
  if (
    window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes('safari') &&
    window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().includes('mobile') &&
    document.documentElement.clientHeight > window.innerHeight &&
    !document.hidden
  ) {
    document.querySelector('.callToActionButton').style.bottom = '44px';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.callToActionButton').removeAttribute('style');
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', updatePositionOfCtaButton);
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', updatePositionOfCtaButton);
```

We can also add `transition` to the CTA button to add a little animation

```
.callToActionButton {
  transition: bottom 0.16s linear 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `-webkit-fill-available`

```css
html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

body {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* mobile viewport bug fix */
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>HEADER GOES HERE</header>
<main>MAIN GOES HERE</main>
<footer>FOOTER GOES HERE</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new dvh css unit can help here.

For more info checkout https://web.dev/viewport-units/